# How can I compare two columns, in two different DF, and add value in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have two different DF (`caracteristica_receita` and `coop_receita_anos2d`). I need to compare two columns of them (CNPJ and ANO). If they match, I need to add "1" in a new column (`caracteristica_receita$benford`).

I have been using

```r
caracteristica_receita$benford[which(caracteristica_receita$CNPJ %>%
                                       is.element(coop_receita_anos2d$CNPJ))] <- 1
```

But I don't know how to use this for two columns.

```r
caracteristica_receita <- structure(list(CNPJ = c(1234, 5678, 91012, 12346, 96385, 87952, 
7789, 2535, 4459, 5457), NOME_INSTITUICAO = c("XXXX", 
"AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDDD", 
"RRRR", "FFFFF", 
"GGGGG", "HHHHHH", 
"IIIIIII"), ano_fundacao = c(1993, 
1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994), ANO = c(2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), benford = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("CNPJ", "NOME_INSTITUICAO", 
"ano_fundacao", "ANO", "benford"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And

```r
coop_receita_anos2d <- structure(list(CNPJ = c(1234, 5678, 916862, 12346, 96385, 87952, 
7789, 2535, 4459, 46868), ANO = c(2014, 2014, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("CNPJ", 
"ANO"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 
7L, 11L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 27L, 31L, 35L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, I want:

```r
structure(list(CNPJ = c(1234, 5678, 91012, 12346, 96385, 87952, 
7789, 2535, 4459, 5457), NOME_INSTITUICAO = c("XXXX", 
"AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDDD", 
"RRRR", "FFFFF", 
"GGGGG", "HHHHHH", 
"IIIIIII"), ano_fundacao = c(1993, 
1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994), ANO = c(2014, 
2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), benford = c(1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("CNPJ", "NOME_INSTITUICAO", 
"ano_fundacao", "ANO", "benford"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste the two columns together and use `match`. Convert to boolean and then to integer as follows,

```
as.integer(!is.na(match(do.call(paste, caracteristica_receita[c('CNPJ', 'ANO')]), 
                        do.call(paste, coop_receita_anos2d))))

#[1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

or assign it back to your data frame,

```
caracteristica_receita$benford <- as.integer(!is.na(....))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple base R solution (provided that `df` and `df2` have the same number of records):

```
df <- caracteristica_receita
df2 <- coop_receita_anos2d
ind <- df$ANO == df2$ANO & df$CNPJ == df2$CNPJ
df$benford <- ifelse(ind, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys ! Worked !

Also, my friend sent this answer too:

```
caracteristica_receita$benford[which(str_c(caracteristica_receita$CNPJ, caracteristica_receita$ANO) %>% 
                                    is.element(str_c(coop_receita_anos2d$CNPJ, coop_receita_anos2d$ANO)))] <- 1
```

Thank you so much !